# How to quickly switch what worksheet/workbook is being edited in VBA

Tags: vba

Basically, I want my program to open a hyperlink to another workbook and copy a range of values onto my original workbook. The problem is, I don't know how to properly reference the workbook to "paste" onto

I've tried to replicate a lot of different internet examples. I've tried using "Set" and "With" to switch between them and I've tried to make the original workbook the active workbook before pasting and nothing has been working.

```
Private Sub findColumns_button_Click()  'userform code
    Dim index As Integer, hyperlink_A As Variant, Wb As Worksheet, mainWorkbook As Variant
    mainWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    Worksheets("Data").Cells(2, 2) = ResultA_Combo.Value
    index = findIndex(Cells(2, 2).Value)
    hyperlink_A = findHyperlink(index)
    Worksheets("Data").Cells(3, 2) = hyperlink_A
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=hyperlink_A    'opens correctly
    Dim test As Double
    test = Worksheets("Data").Range("S23")
    MsgBox test 'displays correct value from desired workbook
    Workbooks.Activate Filename:=mainWorkbook   'not sure what to do here


End Sub
```

`MsgBox test` returns the desired value but I can't find a way to set a cell value in the original workbook equal to `test`

Comment: Use a `Workbook` variable: `Dim wb as Workbook`, then `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=...)`. The original workbook is `ThisWorkbook`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps, I've edited your code, and by comparing I hope you get in the right direction... see comments in code for more details:

```vb
Private Sub findColumns_button_Click()  'userform code
    Dim index As Integer, hyperlink_A As Variant, Wb As Worksheet, mainWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim wbSrc As Workbook

    Set mainWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
    With mainWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
        .Cells(2, 2) = ResultA_Combo.Value
        index = findIndex(.Value)
        hyperlink_A = findHyperlink(index)
        .Cells(3, 2) = hyperlink_A
    End With

    Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=hyperlink_A)  'Allocate to variable and open at the same time

    Dim test As Double
    test = mainWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("S23")
    MsgBox test 'displays correct value from first workbook

    mainWorkbook.Activate 'as long you fully qualify the ranges, you don't need and should avoid as much as possible to use .Activate & .Select

    Dim test2 As Double
    wbSrc.Worksheets(1).Range("A1") = mainWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("S23") * 2
    test2 = wbSrc.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")

    MsgBox test2 'displays correct value from second workbook

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm trying to copy a range of values from the 'opened' workbook and paste them onto my original workbook - I think this does the opposite?

Comment: You are correct, but that was for testing purposes only... if you want to copy, the easiest way is to use the example above, just reverse the workbooks, i.e. instead of `workbook_A.Range.Value = workbook_B.Range.Value`, do `workbook_B.Range.Value = workbook_A.Range.Value`. It is as simple as that :)